# Convert rows to column using powershell

Tags: powershell, split

```
I have below input file
```

===============================
For Oct 01 07:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)
Total calls:                    828303
Total refresh calls:            0
Total backup calls:             828303

```
For Oct 01 11:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)
Total calls:                    833044
Total refresh calls:            13
Total backup calls:             833031

Like to convert above as below

Date                                            Total Calls   Total refresh calls  Total backup calls
=====================================================================================================
For Oct 01 07:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)   828303        0                   828303
For Oct 01 11:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)   833044        13                  833031
```

No idea how do i start. so far i come up below code
(((gc .\test.txt) -split '\r?\n').Trim() | where { $_.contains("Total calls") })

Comment: Without properly formatting your sample input text, it makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

So, how I would do this is to use the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet, which will convert Name=Value pairs into hashtables. You read the entire thing in as a single multi-line string. Then split it into records by splitting on lines that begin with `For` . Then replace the colon with equals for the last 3 lines so it looks something like this:

```
For Oct 01 07:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)
Total calls=                   828303
Total refresh calls=           0
Total backup calls=            828303
    

For Oct 01 11:00 CST and duration of 4 hour(s)
Total calls=                   833044
Total refresh calls=           13
Total backup calls=            833031
```

The pipe it to a `ForEach-Object` loop that adds a `Date=` to the start of each record makes an object out of each hashtable like this:

```
|ForEach-Object{New-Object psobject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData "Date= $_" )}
```

That will put properties in a kind of random order, so you have to fix that with a `Select-Object` command. In the end you end up with code that looks something like this:

```
Get-Content test.txt -raw
$RawText -split '(?m)^(?=For)' -replace '(?m)^([^:]+): (.*)$','$1=$2'|
    ForEach-Object{
        New-Object psobject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData "Date= $_" )
    }|Select Date,'Total Calls','Total refresh calls','Total backup calls'
```